# Ember: how to use i18n translations in controller code?

Tags: ember.js

I am using Ember i18n in my app.  I also want to use the translation strings in the controllers (in most cases in an alert or confirm message).  How can this be done ?

See http://jsfiddle.net/cyclomarc/36VS3/2/

Clicking on the button should alert "info" and not "T1005" ...

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{t T1005}}<br>
    <button {{action 'clickMe' content}}>{{t T1005}} - Click me</button>
</script>

CLDR.defaultLanguage = 'en';

App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    clickMe: function(){
        alert('T1005');
    }
})
```

I know that a possible workaround is to no longer use alert and confirm and replace them by for example the bootstrap alternatives.  However, I could imagine that in certain cases you will want to do something with the strings in Javascript (e.g. update a certain label via jQuery or so).

Any ideas on how to use the i18n strings in the controllers is helpful.  Using an i18n library is only usefull if all aspects of the application can be translated ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be late here, but what about using the `Em.I18n.TranslateableProperties` mixin as documented [here](https://github.com/jamesarosen/ember-i18n#translate-properties-on-any-object) ?

You could do something like :

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend(Em.I18n.translateableProperties, {
    messageTranslation: 'T1005',

    clickMe: function(){
        alert(this.get('message'));
    }
});
```

In the template, `{{message}}` will also hold the translation.

Answer (score 4):

Just found the solution. Just access the string via `Ember.I18n.t("T1005");`

JSFiddle updated: http://jsfiddle.net/cyclomarc/36VS3/7/

Answer (score 0):

The solution that works to me is the following (using Ember I18n):

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend(Em.I18n.translateableProperties, {
  messageTranslation: 'T001',

  showMessage: function(){
    alert(this.get('message'));
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer from cyclomarc didn't work for me (it's from 2013, which might be related), but it pointed me in the right direction:

```
this.container.lookup('service:i18n').t('my.translation.id')
```

Comment: Why lookup ? Why not just injecting service like `i18n:Ember.inject.service()` will get i18n service object.

Comment: True (and I just learned this.container is deprecated). The point is: Either way one can get a translated String from within a controller, which answers the question. btw: A case where I prefer the `lookup` way is when used in an `else`. I do not need to inject the service _every_ time if only used _some_ times

Comment: [reference for deprecation](https://www.emberjs.com/deprecations/v2.x/#toc_deprecations-added-in-2-3). We can use `Ember.getOwner(this).lookup` instead of `this.container`